# Разниться время в таймере (между php и js)

Tags: javascript, php, время

Столкнулся с проблемой, что на стороне клиента таймер на несколько секунд впереди, в сравнении с с сервером.

При обновлении страницы сперва интервал выводиться со стороны сервера, а после инициализации js таймер начинает срабатывать и отсчитывает время, но на несколько секунд быстрее нежели со стороны сервера.

Ниже привожу часть кода с бэка и фронта.

**бэк php:**

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$midnight =  new DateTime('tomorrow 00:00');
$interval = $now->diff($midnight);
$this->assign('interval', $interval->format('<span>%H:%I:%S</span>'));

$this->assign('eventTime', $midnight->format('U'));
$this->assign('currentTime', $now->format('U'));
```

**фронт html:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg timer-numbers" id="bonus-left">{{ (user.next_bonus >= eventTime ? 'Осталось ' ~ interval : 'Получить бонус')|raw }}</button>
<div id="countdown" class="timer-line"><span></span></div>
```

**фронт js:**

```
let currentTime = +'{{ currentTime * 1000 }}';
eventTime = +'{{ eventTime * 1000 }}';

class Countdown {
    constructor(timer, countdown, from, to) {
        this.timer = timer;
        this.countdown = countdown;
        this.start = from;
        this.finish = to;
        this.run();
    }

    run() {
        let distance = this.finish - this.start,
            days, hours, minutes, seconds,
            percent;

        let countdown = setInterval(_ => {
            let point = new Date().getTime() - this.start,
                localDistance = this.finish - new Date().getTime();

            days = Math.max(0, Math.floor(localDistance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
            hours = Math.max(0, Math.floor((localDistance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)));
            minutes = Math.max(0, Math.floor((localDistance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)));
            seconds = Math.max(0, Math.floor((localDistance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000));

            percent = point * 100 / distance;

            if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0 || percent >= 100) clearInterval(countdown);
            if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
                takeBonus(countdown); // exit
                return false;
            }

            this.countdown.children[0].innerText =
                (hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours) + ':' +
                (minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes) + ':' +
                (seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds);

            this.timer.querySelector('.timer-line > span').style.width = `${percent}%`;
        }, 1000);
    }
}

window.onload = _ => {
    new Countdown(
        document.getElementById('countdown'),
        document.getElementById('countdown').previousElementSibling,
        currentTime,
        eventTime
    );
};
```

Если есть вопросы по коду, пишите!
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: а зачем два таймера?

Comment: Здравствуйте, таймер один, с бэка просто выводиться интервал (так как js может инициализироваться некоторое время, что бы место где будет таймер не было пусто, а после его инициализации уже начинает работать таймер через js)